# Need help printing out a string

Tags: c++

Im currently learning about classes in C++. Im coming from a java language background.

I have a class called animals. the animals constructor has a parameter in which a string is required. When i create an object of that class and try to print out the string that was passed to the constructor, it doesn't print out anything apart from a new line..

ANIMAL CLASS

```
    #include "animal.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


animal::animal(string nameofanimal)
{

    string name = nameofanimal;
}

void animal::getName(){
    cout << name << endl;
}
```

ANIMAL HEADER:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class animal
{

private:
    string name;

public:
    animal(string x);
    void getName();


};

#endif ANIMAL_H
```

MAIN CLASS

```
#include "animal.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    animal firstAnimal("Bob");
    firstAnimal.getName();

}
```

the output is nothing. this is a very basic code and honestly cant believe I don't know how to do such a simple task. What I have noticed is that whenever I highlight the name varible in the animals constructor, the varible name in the getName() function doesn't highlight so im guessing this has something to do with pointers... I may be wrong though...

Comment: have a look at the code inside of your constructor.  does anything about it look off?

Comment: Like Sam says.  Scope...

Comment: Change the name of `getName()` to `printNameToStdOut`, because that is what is attempts to do.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `animal` constructor definition as follows

```
animal::animal(string nameofanimal) : name(nameofanimal) {
}
```

In your original definiton you have a local variable `name` that shadows the class member variable:

```
animal::animal(string nameofanimal)
{    
    string name = nameofanimal; // <<< This sets only the local variable
}
```

Comment: To avoid such errors in the future, it is best to use style conventions of variable naming. For example, add an underscore to each class member variable at the end (name_), prepend it with an "m_" (m_name) or capitalize it (Name). This makes it much harder to mix up local and member variables.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy Besides it's a good idea to have a style convention for class member variables, I don't see how this should really help to prevent such error as shown in the OP's sample. Usually this kind of error occurs, because the declaration code is copy pasted to the constructor body, and filled in. The only way to really prevent this, is to use the member initializer list, as shown in my sample.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are storing value in local variable

```
string name = nameofanimal;
```

while the value is not stored in actual data member of the class.  To store it in data member use the following:

```
name = nameofanimal;
```